# Server SSH Fingerprint Failed to Verify

Tags: xcode, github, ssh

I've got a local Swift Package Manager package that uses a private Github repo as a dependency. When I open the local package with Xcode, it fails to “Resolve Packages” with this error:

> Error while fetching remote repository: git@github.com:mayoff/Preamble.git
>
> > Server SSH Fingerprint Failed to Verify

[image: Xcode error log showing the errors described above]

However, if I use the command line `swift` program, it can clone the private repo. For example, I can run `swift package show-dependencies` in the local package's directory without complaint. I can also successfully clone the remote package repo with `git clone`. So it's not a problem with my `.known_hosts` file or my SSH key.

How do I fix Xcode's complaint?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

So it turns out the “Server SSH Fingerprint Failed to Verify” error message in Xcode's log navigator is **double-clickable**. Who'd have guessed?

Anyway, double-clicking the error message brought up a dialog box that let me tell Xcode to trust the Github server:

[image: Xcode dialog box with a Trust button]

After I clicked the Trust button, Xcode was able to clone the remote repo.

Comment: Have you tried looking for culprits? Is it so that github decided to put up extra servers? Was there some sort of expiration for current keys?

Comment: How in the world is that even remotely discoverable? I'm curious... is there any other way to resolve this issue? One might think resetting package caches would also (maybe) reset ssh fingerprints?

Comment: Mind blown. This is not obvious.

Comment: How you decide to try double click that in the first place?

Comment: Can I achieve the same behavior using the command line? Because I have to setup several CI machines using ssh, without interface

Comment: Sadly this is crashing on Xcode 13.4.1 for me

Answer (score 1):

You can also edit the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file and remove the entry for `github.com` and let it try and resolve it again. This applies to any other website that may have had its certificate changed since the last time you tried to `ssh`.

Comment: Xcode keeps its own list of known SSH hosts. And the fingerprint being shown doesn't match any of github.com's fingerprints: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints

I'm seeing this behaviour myself, and it's deeply concerning.

Comment: This was the answer for me. Instead of randomly trusting a bad domain, I just nuked the known_hosts file (it only had info on my Git servers), and then Xcode's SwiftPM bits were happy. That way, Xcode will still do its usual checks and the only thing you circumvent is the complaint that a certificate has been changed, but it still ensures it's valid for that domain.

Comment: (And yes, cloning the repo was fine in Terminal for me)